# Posting form data with Ajax but post data gets truncated at server

Tags: php, forms, jquery, post

I am sending form data with 2k+ parameters, but server only recieves less than half of it.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'inner.php?option=param',
    type: 'POST',
    data: $('#form').serialize(),
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
        //success action
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions){
        //error action
    }  
});
```

Some of the paramerters are posted by Ajax are-

```
1190583_1306134[]   1
1226739_1343934[]
```

My application is written in PHP. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats [LimitRequestBody](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody) on apache if you are using it?

Comment: I've found that PHP will not parse the POST data if it's too large. So you either get everything or nothing. Are you sure you're receiving a partial request?

Comment: check your php.ini file and find post_max_size

Comment: use dataType as json and encode this data in your inner.php file

Comment: @user1190992: initially LimitRequestBody was set to 0, I have changed it 102400. But still no success.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen: Yes, I'm receiving some part of posted data.

Comment: @GGio: post_max_size is set to 128M.

Comment: I highly suggest you check Apache error log to find out exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need not to post the *empty elements*.

Replace data: `$('#form').serialize()`

with data: `$('#form :input[value!='']').serialize()`.

Hopefully it will work for you.

Comment: your solution worked, though, my question is going unanswered :(

Answer (score 1):

Just wasted 2h on exactly the same thing - partial $_POST data in php backend (~1000 out of ~3500).

Found this in apache logs:

`Warning: Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini. in Unknown on line 0, referer: http://app1.local/full_path`

That was more than sufficient to uncomment `max_input_vars` in php.ini, change it to 10000 and restart apache. All was working again after that ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I don't know why but $.ajax trucantes post data passed as string.

To solve this use object data instead.

For example

```
$data=$('form').serialize();
$data=JSON.parse('{"' + decodeURI($data.replace(/&/g, "\",\"").replace(/=/g,"\":\"")) + '"}');
$.ajax({
       url:$url,
       data:$data,
       ...
});
```

Hope this will help ;)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding the error **Request has been truncated** when using direct form pickup via **data: new FormData(this)** on the *Firefox debuger-console*, the whole data may have actually been posted and the error seems to be false. I had to spend several hours only to realize that *Google Chrome* does not report the error and on actual check-up of the image being posted, it was actually being uploaded.

By the way, a direct form pickup as such does not require the **serialization** and can upload even images.